# Using the slug rather than ID in django rest framework with json api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My member app expects the JSON response to contain a primary key result for the model ID. Rather than use integer IDs, I want to use slugs. I know that in the standard django framework you can do something like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Page

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   id = serializers.CharField(source='slug')

   class Meta:
      model = Page
      fields = ('name','id',...etc )
```

However, this doesn't work when using the json API - in my response I still have something like

```
"data": [{
        "type": "pages",
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Some page name",                 
        }]
```

When I want the "id" field to be something like "some-page-name" (the slug)

Is this not possible with the json API. For clarity the equivalent json API import above would be

```
 from rest_framework_json_api import serializers
```

Many thanks

**** addition ****

To help clarify the problem I am facing, here is a serializer using the standard REST framework. All attributes shown below are included in the Page model.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Page

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='slug')
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('name','id')
```

The JSON response I get at http://localhost:8000/api/pages is as follows

```
 [
    {
      "name": "Page 1",
      "id": "page-1"
   },
   {
    "name": "Page 2",
    "id": "page-2"
   },
   {
     etc
   }
 ]
```

When I use the json API, doing the exactly the same, but obviously importing

```
from rest_framework_json_api import serializers
```

I am not able to change the id value in the same way, I have something like this when viewing http://localhost:8000/api/pages

```
{
   "links": {
      omitted for brevity ...
   },
  "data": [
      {
        "type": "pages",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Page 1"
        }
     },
     {
        "type": "pages",
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Page 2"
       }
    },
]
```

Comment: don't include `'id'` in `fields`.

Comment: do you have the field slug in your model?

Comment: If your model has a `slug` field, why not just pass that as field (and give it the label "id")?

Comment: Hi - thanks for getting back. If I remove 'id' in fields it makes no difference, and sorry, yes I do have slug in the model .. I didnt show it in the fields list for brevity

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry can you clarify?

Comment: `slug = serializers.SlugField(label='id')`

Comment: @dirkgroten I think he wants to pass in the slug as the parameter to the url and he is not able to explain it clearly.

Comment: I don't want to pass in the slug as a parameter to the url - please see comment below

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution which allows me to view responses at eg http://localhost:8000/api/pages and make a request to http://localhost:8000/api/pages/some-slug in a format that Emberjs (expecting the response to conform with the JSON API spec) won't complain about.

In my serializer (PageSerializer.py):

```
from rest_framework_json_api import serializers
from .models import Page

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('name','id','url','slug')
        lookup_field = 'slug'

        // if you want to show the links field in the response
        extra_kwargs = {'url': {'lookup_field':'slug'}}
```

In the view (PageViewSet)

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Page
from .serializers import PageSerializer

class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Page.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

The router stays unchanged:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from page import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register('pages',views.PageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('api/',include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use your slug field instead of id as your primary key so that you can pass that parameter in your url to get the desired result.
You can do something like this in your url

```
url(r'^something-here/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', "your_view_name_here", name='name_you_want')
```

In your views then you can do something like the following:

```
class YourListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return ModelName.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining this more clearly - I was hoping by giving the example from the standard REST framework in my original question that there would be a simple way to achieve the same thing using the json api. In the json response (shown in the original question), the "id" field needs to show the slug. I don't think this achieves that but apologies if I'm mistaken

Comment: I think you are thinking in the wrong way. Your end result is to use id as the parameter in the url so that you can pass the slug in the url and get a response. Right?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I would want to be able to use the slug to obtain the instance response eg http://localhost:8000/api/pages/some-page versus http://localhost:8000/api/pages/1 but when viewing the response for all pages at http://localhost:8000/api/pages, that response needs to include the slug value for the id, not the integer - please see amended question above. I can achieve this using the "standard" DRF (see amended question) but not getting the same result when I use the rest_framework_json_api, which is what I want.

Comment: @Newfoundland id is a default field and a default primary key. As you said you already have slug in your model field. Use that field as your url parameter. Change your url as mentioned above in my answer so that it accepts the slug when you are going to call the API url. After that just use the slug and do something in your view.

Comment: Sorry but can't get this to work. If I use the generics.ListAPIView in my view, utilising the PageSerializer class which consumes the serializers.ModelSerializer from rest_framework_json_api, I get this error AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute. Don't worry I'll just change the primary key in my Django models to be the slug.

Comment: @Newfoundland Can you paste your code from your view. You can override the queryset using get_queryset() method. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188695/discussion-between-newfoundland-and-indexoutofbounds).

Comment: I have a solution, which allows me to have the response I need on /api/pages and allows for a query api/pages/some-slug. I've answered the question - many thanks for your input